# android studio crashes automatically

Tags: android

My android studio crashes in between giving various exception errors(blue screen) like system_service_exception(idmwfp.sys),or system_thread_exception_not_handled(nvlddmkm.sys).
Previously I had changed(increased) virtual memory of my system, at that time AS used to crash within minutes of starting up and now that I have set virtual memory to automatic it takes about 15 minutes to crash.I have downloaded, installed and uninstall ,reinstall AS 4-5 times but same problem exists. I have checked all related answers but none helped. Please help....

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with AS. A Windows blue screen is caused by driver errors - the drivers you have listed are the Internet Download Manager WFP Driver (idmwfp.sys) and an Nvidia graphics driver (nvlddmkm.sys).